# What is the simplest way to wrap an object such that the wrapper __call__ calls the wrapped objects __getitem__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x, wrapper

Consider the following code snippet:

```
dikt =  {
  "City": "Denver",
  "State": "Colorado",
  "Street": "123 Nowhere St."
}

kal = wrap(dikt)

assert(kal("City") == dikt["City"])
assert(kal("State") == dikt["State"])
```

What is the simplest way to implement the `wrap` function? We want the wrapper's `__call__` method to call the wrapped objects `__getitem__` method.

Answer (score 5):

Simple in the case of straightforward is to just implement a basic wrapper class which defines `__call__` in those terms:

```
class wrap:
    def __init__(self, mapping):
       self.mapping = mapping

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.mapping[x]
```

Slightly shorter (and at least on CPython, slightly faster to call), but less configurable/inspectable/extensible is a function factory using closures:

```
def wrap(mapping):
    def wrapped(x):
        return mapping[x]
    return wrapped
```

Lastly, and most simply (but least configurably), there is directly returning the bound `__getitem__`:

```
def wrap(mapping):
    return mapping.__getitem__
```

or using existing tools to push even the binding to C (on CPython anyway):

```
from operator import attrgetter

wrap = attrgetter('__getitem__')
```

No actual definition of the final callable is made here, you're just binding the existing method and returning it.

Comment: I refuse to include this in the answer, because it should not actually be used to solve the problem, but since the wrapping is *so* simple, you could actually one-line the factory function/closure solution as: `wrap = lambda m: lambda x: m[x]` If you use that for anything but code golfing, expect your fellow developers to set your code (and possibly you for good measure) on fire.

Comment: I  think that it's worth mentioning that last approach can eliminate need for wrapper: `kal =  dikt.__getitem__`

Comment: @imposeren: Yeah, I was just in the process of distilling it to the simplest form. I wanted to keep it named as `wrap` for reuse, but yeah, `dikt.__getitem__` works on its own; `operator.attrgetter` can just make a `wrap` function for reuse that does that without retyping `__getitem__` each time.

Comment: We could also have `wrap = operator.methodcaller(`__getitem__`)